# conditional distribution for a discrete RV

Tags: probability, probability-theory

For a discrete RV $X$, is it true that the conditional distribution $P_{X \mid Y} (B \mid y)$ is discrete as well for all $y$?

I only managed to prove that this is true almost surely. Let $\Pr(X\in C) = 1$ for countable $C$, then by definition $\Pr (X \in C, Y \in \mathbb{R}) =\mathbf{E} [P_{X \mid Y} (C \mid Y) ; Y \in \mathbb{R}] = 1$.

Comment: What does RV stand for?

Comment: @5xum random variable.

Comment: How do you define "discrete", if not taking values in a countable set almost surely?

Comment: What is $B$ in $P_{X \mid Y} (B \mid y)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose

- $Y$ is uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$
- given $Y=y \in \mathbb{Q}$ you have $X$ uniformly distributed on $[0,2y]$
- given $Y=y \not \in \mathbb{Q}$ you have $X=1$ with probability $y$ and $X=0$ with probability $1-y$

then you can say various things such as $E[X \mid Y=y] = y$, $\,E[X]=E[Y]=\frac12$, $\Pr(X=0)=\Pr(X=1)=\frac12$ and the marginal distribution of $X$ is discrete, but the conditional distribution of $X$ given $y=\frac12$ is continuous.

Comment: The conditional distribution of $X$ given $Y=y$ is also Bernoulli$(y)$, for *every* $y$.